# Get parameter from the form

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

In phonegap, I uses one jquery mobile framework. And I want to pass the form data to next page which is a div by using page url. I tries to use GetElementByID to retrieve the parameter. It shows me "[object HTMLDivElement]". I is not the result I wanted. How can I solve it?

Down below is the function that change to next page DIV is the code of my phonegap:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#home').live('pagecreate',function(event) { 
    $("#form").submit( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var x=document.getElementById("search");
            $.mobile.changePage("#page1?param1="+x);
    });
});
</script>
```

And the form html:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="page1" data-ajax="false">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="search">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="search">
                            Search
                        </label>
                        <input name="search" id="search" placeholder="" value="" type="search" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchmethod">
                    <label for="searchmethod">
                    </label>
                    <select id="searchmethod" name="searchmethod" data-theme="e">
                        <option value="keyword">
                            Keyword
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchlocation">
                    <label for="searchlocation">
                    </label>
                    <select name="searchlocation" data-theme="e">
                        <option value="Entire Collection">
                            Entire Collection
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one HTML element with the id "search", which is bad. IDs are supposed to be unique. When you call the pure javascript function `getElementById`, it returns the first match, which is the `<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="search">`.

You should change the ID of either the DIV or the INPUT. Then you can use what joeframbach suggested:

```
var x=document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
```

or you could use jQuery to select the element and get its value:

```
var x=$("input#search").val();
```

To get the search method and search location for the HTML structure in the question:

```
var method=$("select#searchmethod").val();

var location=$("select[name='searchlocation']").val(); // locate element by name since ID is not set
```

Comment: If I want to get the parameter of `searchmethod` and `searchlocation`, How can I do it?

Comment: @helloeveryone you have the same duplicate ID problem for those fields too. You should be able to use: `var method=$("input#searchmethod").val();` and `var location=$("input#searchlocation").val();`

Comment: It is fine to get parameter for method,but it shows undefined for location. I re-write the code for problem of duplicated ID. What is the problem?
`<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchcondition2">
                        <label for="searchlocation2">
                        </label>
                        <select name="searchlocation" id="searchlocation" data-theme="e">
                            <option value="Entire Collection">
                                Entire Collection
                            </option>
                        </select>`

Comment: @helloeveryone It was undefined because I didn't notice that searchlocation did not have its `ID` field set. In fact, I'm surprised it worked for `searchmethod`, because the selector I suggested is wrong. It should be `var method=$("select#searchmethod").val();` or just `var method=$("#searchmethod").val();` if you changed the html so the ID is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just noticed you have two elements with id `search`. You should change this. Not only is it confusing to anyone who reads your code, but it also causes problems like the one you're experiencing here. `getElementById` returns the **first** element with the specified ID. In your case, that's a div, not the input.

If you really want to stick to what you have, though, you could do this:

```
var x = $('input#search').val(); //Suggesting jQuery since you're already using it.
```

Edit: Per your comment, here's how to do it. jQuery's `val()` function has really good support for `select`s and checkboxes. All you have to do is call `val()` on the select element itself, and it'll return the currently selected value. So, do it like this:

```
$("[name='searchmethod']").val();
$("[name='searchlocation']").val();
```

I'd really suggest doing it by ID rather than name, though. I did it by name because, like before, you had multiple elements with the same ID. This is a no-no in 99% of situations.

Comment: OP probably wants the value that is typed in the input.

Comment: @tcovo oh, I was looking at the other element with id "search". Didn't notice the input one. Technically the div would be the one that `getElementById` would have returned in this case, though :)

Comment: If I want to get the parameter of `searchmethod` and `searchlocation`, How can I do it?

Comment: @helloeveryone I edited my post with information on how to get those values. Please remember to accept an answer if you feel that it has satisfied the needs in the original question (whether that answer was mine or not)